# Counting entry in a column MySQL and display counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I would want to count entries in a column and display the count beside it.
However, I'm clueless on how can I do it.

Desired output:

```
arrangement_number      tray_no  rl_type  flag(count of occurrence)
------------------      -------  ----     ----
2774818                 381001   R        3
2774818                 381001   R        3
2774818                 381001   L        3
2778470                 405128   R        1
2779702                 265265   R        2
2779702                 265265   R        2
```

I'm currently trying queries using `@variables` but I still cant get it right.
each row are unique and I need them not to be grouped.

Update: Expanded Table added source code

Note: I'm currently joining 5 tables now

Actual Query:

```
SELECT 
    log.arrangement_number,
    header.tray_number,
    detail.rl_type,

    -- some more fields here

FROM
    log
        INNER JOIN
    header ON log.arrangement_number = header.rxarrangement_number
        AND log.production_place_code = header.production_place_code
        INNER JOIN
    detail ON log.arrangement_number = detail.rxarrangement_number
        AND log.production_place_code = detail.production_place_code
        INNER JOIN
    deliveryperiod ON log.arrangement_number = deliveryperiod.arrangement_number
        AND log.production_place_code = deliveryperiod.production_place_code
        AND detail.rl_type = deliveryperiod.rl_type
        INNER JOIN
    calc ON calc.arrangement_number = log.arrangement_number
        AND calc.production_place_code = log.production_place_code
        AND deliveryperiod.rl_type = calc.rl_type
        AND detail.rl_type = calc.rl_type
WHERE
    header.status_code IN ('20' , '21')
        AND log.process_code = '12'
        AND deliveryperiod.process_code_current = '12'
        AND deliveryperiod.sub_process_code_current IN ('100' , '105')
        AND lot_number = '120131'
ORDER BY log.lot_number , log.sequence_number , deliveryperiod.rl_type DESC
```

Comment: `SELECT tray_no, COUNT(*) AS flag FROM table GROUP BY tray_no`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Careful: If he wants to also retain all the original records, then you probably have to use a subquery.

Comment: I cant use `GROUP BY` I need the flags for each row. I slimmed it down.

Comment: Table structure and sample data would be helpful... Are you looking for the `mysql` equivalent to `count/over`?  @TimBiegeleisen provides a good solution below.  Alternatives include correlated subqueries and user defined variables...

Comment: Added source code. I've been tinkering with this query since yesterday..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.tray_no,
       t2.flag
FROM yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tray_no, COUNT(*) AS flag
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY tray_no
) t2
    ON t1.tray_no = t2.tray_no
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT tray_no, COUNT(*) 'flag'
FROM table1
GROUP BY tray_no
```